# phonegap deviceready event - ripple emulator

Tags: cordova

hello all
Im having some problems with the initial phonegap 'deviceready' event-handler not being triggered properly, in the ripple chrome extension phonegap emulator.

```
<script src="xui-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.4.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script> -->
<script>
    function onLoad() {
        //console.log(document);
        /*document.addEventListener('deviceready',function() {
                console.log('PHONEGAP_READY');
            },false);*/
        console.log('ON_LOAD');
        x$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
                console.log('PHONEGAP_READY');
            }, false);
    }

</script>
```

so the issue is that the console.log('PHONEGAP_READY') is never run. I used XUI here just to try the way the official ripple phonegap demos work (ones posted on their page). neither that, nor the document.addEventListener(), work... whats strange is that the chrome console output reads "PhoneGap :: fired deviceready event!" so Im assuming the event really is firing, but the event handler itself is not being called...
any clues are appreciated

thanks

Comment: Hey Deepblue, When do you call your onload function? You won't set the handler until that function is invoked.

Comment: I omitted that from the listing here for brevity purposes. Im doing it in <body onload="onLoad();"></body>

Comment: Sorry I can't answer - just wanted to add that I ran into this same problem, so I started a new Eclipse project without any of my own Java or js, followed the quickstart-HelloWorld instructions to the letter and I get the same result, deploying to a DROIDX. No error messages in Logcat, but the "deviceready" event handler is never called. Maybe it has something to do with overriding document.addEventListener?

Comment: @Brandon - yes, in phonegap.0.9.4.js document.addEventListener is overridden at line 338... as you say perhaps it has something to do with that. mind you, in this case Im running things inside chrome/ripple so no Eclipse/android packaging is involved...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a quirk in how ripple emulates the runtime for phonegap: [docs here](http://rippledocs.tinyhippos.com/index.html#platforms/phoneGap)

ripple will inject the phonegap runtime before the document loads and if you include the phonegap.js file in your app it will override the ripple emulated environment and that may cause issues.

Try removing the phonegap source from your page and reloading to see if that helps.

Comment: yyyyyeeeeesssss! :) thanks Gord. btw you guys made a hell of a tool. thank you

Comment: Thank you, removing the cordova-2.7.0.js inclusing from my index.html file and using the URL example mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15317390/763010) worked for me.

Comment: Ripple has moved to Apache! is there any alternative link?

Answer (score 9):

I've spent hours trying to fix this as well. 
What will help is manually setting the Cordova Platform version to 2.0 in the Ripple UI (Left pane > Platforms > Version: change from 1.0 to 2.0). It's quite silly, I was calling Ripple with this URL

```
http://localhost?enableripple=cordova-2.7.0-Nexus4
```

but I still had to change the settings manually to finally get it to run. That's because Ripple doesn't know any version higher than 2.0.0, which makes it simply set the platform version to 1.0.0 in the UI... and then it just uses that.

More details also [on my blog](http://www.iriphon.com/2013/06/09/when-ripple-doesnt-call-the-deviceready-handler-in-your-phonegapcordova-project-set-the-platform-version-manually/).

Comment: This was a life saver. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

try `http://localhost:8080/index.html?enableripple=cordova-2.0.0`, this works for me to fire deviceready event

Comment: Thank you! This and a combination of @Gord's answer worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me, just matching de cordova-x.0.0 to the one in the installed cordova `package.json`, e.g in my windows `C:\Users\drodsou\AppData\Roaming\ npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova`

Answer (score 2):

> Include Cordova Script in your html file as follows.

```
    <script  src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI changing cordova-x.x.x in the query string to the version installed in your app also causes device ready to fire in the updated version of ripple http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn.

```
http://localhost:4400/?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0 (Default, not firing)

http://localhost:4400/?enableripple=cordova-3.2.0 (Changed to my version, firing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above suggestions here is a full index.js for a Visual Studio 2015 RC cordova app (editing the provided template):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function bootstrapAngular() {
    console.log("Bootstrapping AngularJS");
    // This assumes your app is named "app" and is on the body tag: <body ng-app="app">
    // Change the selector from "body" to whatever you need
    var domElement = document.querySelector('body');
    // Change the application name from "app" if needed
    angular.bootstrap(domElement, ['app']);
    }
    if (document.URL.indexOf('http://') === -1
        && document.URL.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
        console.log("URL: Running in Cordova/PhoneGap");
        //document.addEventListener("deviceready", bootstrapAngular, false);
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    } else {
        console.log("URL: Running in browser");
        bootstrapAngular();
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        bootstrapAngular();
    };
    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };
    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
} )();
```

Also, they don't really point it out above but you shouldn't put anything in your body tag to make this work.  The fuctions do that for you.  Finally, don't forget to apply ng-controller somewhere, you still have to specify that.