# Onload event fires twice and deviceready does not fire at all

Tags: cordova, onload, ripple

I am using Ripple 0.9.9 to test my PhoneGap 2.0 app but am having trouble setting it up.  I've read related questions on this site, but nothing which addresses my issues:

According to [phonegap deviceready event - ripple emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187089/phonegap-deviceready-event-ripple-emulator) - the ripple emulator injects ripple.js into the page and this contains the phonegap api emulator. So, don't include your phonegap.js/cordova.js in your page when testing inside Ripple.

Using `<body onload="onLoad()">` to call my onload handler I have the following JavaScript:

```
var mobile=false;

function onLoad() {
console.info("inside onload...");
var uA = navigator.userAgent;
if (uA.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
    console.info("on phone: " + navigator.userAgent);
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { mobile=true; appReady(); }, false);
} else {
    if (uA.match(/Chrome/)) {
        console.info("on browser: " + navigator.userAgent + ", do not initiate mobile app for Chrome since will be init. by Ripple");

    } else {
        /* not running on Chrome so no Ripple */
        appReady();
    }
}

}
```

When I run my index.html inside of the Ripple emulator (set to Phonegap/Cordova 2.0) running on an iPhone 4 I see the following debug (init.js is my js file) :

```
inside onload... init.js:19

on browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) 

Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11, do not initiate mobile app for Chrome since will be init. by Ripple init.js:26

Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.) ripple.js:475

cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.) ripple.js:475

inside onload... init.js:19

on phone: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A542a Safari/419.3
```

I can see that the onload event is fired twice: a) for the normal browser and b) it seems that ripple changes the user-agent to that of an iPhone 4 and then reloads the page.

Is this normal behaviour?

The 'deviceready' event is never called. Any idea why not?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this Jeremy? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the deviceready event, make sure that you have the phonegap platform enabled from the left-hand "Platforms" panel in Ripple.  If a non-PhoneGap platform is being used, then I would imagine the deviceready event would not be fired.

As for the double page reload, yes that was a temporary behavior of Ripple designed to force certain page events to occur in necessary order.  However the latest version (0.9.11) has fixed the issue.  You should not see Ripple forcing an additional page load after your content has already been loaded.

Recommend updating to 0.9.11