# "Require" exception in Cordova/phonegap project

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

I am trying to build an hybrid mobile app using Phonegap/Cordova in Android platform. And I have succeeded in that too :) The app works as desired in Ripple emulator in my Chrome browser. I am not using Eclipe ADT or Android Studio as the emulator does not load quick.

I have used onDeviceReady event and Navigator plugin for vibrate and alerts. All these works fine as expected.

When the Developer Console is active in Chrome, the JavaScript breaks in cordova.js with the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

in the following line. The same happens for notification.js file too. When I press continue in debugger, everything works again as expected apart from that error.

```
var cordova_events = require('./src/events'),
```

Order of the java script files are as given below.

```
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/notification.js"></script>               
<script src="js/vibration.js"></script>
```

I believe I am not referencing the correct cordova.js file and all other dependencies. But I also wonder how come does the app works fine in Ripple when the developer console is not active.

I even tried to remove cordova.js file as Ripple automatically includes it as per [phonegap deviceready event - ripple emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187089/phonegap-deviceready-event-ripple-emulator)

I have the download copies of phonegap and cordova from their respective sites. I have installed Node.js and have installed the packages too.

**My questions here are:**

- Where to find the correct cordova.js file? Which is the correct version to be included in my html files project?
- What's the user of Node.js over here?
- Does it designed to automatically include the scripts based on Node.js? If so what I am missing?

I confess that the concept and usage of node.js looks like a rocket science for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cordova and Phonegap are pretty much the same thing, you shouldn't need to download both. Cordova is the open source project that helps you publish your HTML5 app to multiple different mobile OSes. Phonegap uses Cordova to do that, but also adds some extra features, mostly just being able to build in the cloud instead of on your workstation.

Node.js is used by Cordova for a lot of the building steps. Since Cordova works on OSX and Windows machines, we needed a way to write build and package scripts that would work on both operating systems - node.js provides this. When you build an application with Cordova you shouldn't really use node.js at all, unless you are also building a complementary backend system.

Starting with Cordova 3.x, there is a `cordova` command line tool that can greatly help you create the application. It takes care of copying the right cordova.js and cordova-android.jar files. You can read about it here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Once you get set up you might want to read my other answer that clarifies some of the use cases of `cordova` tool: [Should a phonegap plugin be declared in the config.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112436/should-a-phonegap-plugin-be-declared-in-the-config-xml-file/19125861#19125861)

Comment: Thanks for response. I got some idea on this. I am aware that cordova and phonegap are almost the same. I just downloaded to try which cordova.js file actually works.I built a new project using CLI and copied the cordova.js to my non-cli based project(eclipe project). Still I get the same error in question.

Comment: Is there any way I can get in touch with chat or email? Seems like you are an expert in Phonegap. I am a legacy mainframe COBOL developer starting with this after working on PHP. :)

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be using the CLI and Eclipse at the same time. It's okay to use the CLI to set up the project and then in Eclipse do "New Android Project From Existing Code" and point to your `/cordovaCli/myApp/platforms/android/` folder. We are referring to this workflow (with eclipse) as the 'native platform dev'. I've been trying to clarify the two workflows in the documentation: https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/pull/140 Hopefully I can finish it this week. During the workday I try to lurk in #cordova and #phonegap on freenode, you can ping me there.....what's COBOL? ;) lol jk

Comment: That was a great piece of information in github cordova docs.. I was thinking why there are 2 www folders in CLI project.. one is root and one in platforms\android\assets\. Which www folder is actualy to be edited for building the app? Why there are 2 www and some content in both? Looks like content are also same..

Comment: Yeah I tried to clarify that in the stackoverflow answer posted above and in the new docs. You should edit the root www folder and let the CLI tools copy that content into appropriate /www/ folders for each platform. This is because ios, android, etc., store their /www/ assets in different locations. You could think of things in /platforms/ folder as build artifacts. There are some cases where you can edit those files, but any changes will be wiped out by the CLI commands.

Comment: Sorry to ask silly things.. in your previous comment, you mentioned to step up the project from myApp/platforms/android/.. so I thought thats the actual source to start with.. Now I understand that the root is the one to be modified..

Comment: I would suggest to provide those details in the guithub doc so that some lame users (like me) will understand it well :)

Comment: BTW, I voted for some French language tranlsations for cordova docs.. My small contribution :D

Answer (score 6):

**Dont use the plugins *.js files out of the plugin source.**

**Dont add plugins *.js files as  tags into your html**
(Cordova loads them on its own based on cordova_plugins.js )

The specific error 'require is not defined' comes from missing cordova define in the plugins.js

```
cordova.define("org.apache.cordova.file.DirectoryEntry", function(require, exports, module) {

});
```

To avoid all of this trouble:

Use [cordova command line interface](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) to setup platforms and plugins. It manages all the native and javascript source files and puts them together in the proper way.