# "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" var channel = require('cordova/channel');

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am facing problem in my  Adobe Phone Gap build project.

I am getting error loading cardova.js on the following line.

```
var channel = require('cordova/channel');
"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
```

I have look around so many places on internet but could not find the solution...

Some people recommended using adding require.js

also that doesn't helped me.

Actually I want to use the InAppBrowser Plugin in my mobile application but for  that requires cardova.js file to be loaded first......

Comment: Hope this link can fix your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818282/require-exception-in-cordova-phonegap-project

Comment: I already gone through these questions before posting new question....   that doesn't solve the problem....